# How can i Populate a List<Object> from a TXT file

Tags: c#, webforms

I need to populate a list with parameters from a TXT file.

This is my Class:

```
 public  class Usuario

{
    private string id;
    private string pass;
    private string rol;

    public string Id { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }

    public string Pass { get { return pass; } set { pass = value; } }

    public string Rol { get { return rol; } set { rol = value; } }

    public Usuario(string id, string pass,string rol)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.rol = rol;
    }

    public Usuario()
    {

    }



}
```

This is my method AddUser:

```
bool User AddUser(string id, string pass)
    {
        if (this.ListUsers == null) this.ListUsers = new List<User>();

        if (id != null && pass != null)
        {
            if (pass.Length >= 6 && pass.Any(char.IsLower) && pass.Any(char.IsDigit) && pass.Any(char.IsUpper))
            {

                    User user = new User()
                    {
                        Id = id,
                        Pass = pass,
                        Rol = "admin"

                    };

                    ListUsers.Add(user);
                    return true;
                }
                else { return false; }
            }
            else { return false; }
        }
        else { return false; }
    }
```

This is the TXT format i need to use: user#password#rol

```
admin1#Admin1234
admin9#Admin1234
```

How can i add Users from the TXT to the Users List by pressing a Button in the WebForm;

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? The reading or the converting a single line into a user object?

Comment: ammm both i guess?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this i guess, no error checking or fault tolerance though

```
var results = File.ReadAllLines("SomeFileName.Text")
                  .Select(x => x.Split('#'))
                  .Select(x => AddUser(x[0], x[1]))
                  .ToList();
```

The rest you can modify to your liking

---

**Additional Resources**

[File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array,
>   and then closes the file.

[Enumerable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

[String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
>   character array.